# Toggle classList of a label on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a to-do list which I want to be able to cross out tasks as they're completed, as well as delete them by clicking their corresponding "X" button.

I use global variable row which is added to different elements' ID. This is how I differentiate them from other task entries.

This works fine when deleting a task, but not when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. I want to toggle the add-strikethrough CSS class whenever a task's checkbox is clicked.

Relevant HTML:

```
    <body>
        <h1>To-Do-List</h1>
        <form action="" onsubmit="createElements();return false" id="todo" autocomplete=off>
            <input type="text" maxlength="25" id="enter-task" placeholder="Enter a Task">
            <button type="button" id="submit-task" onClick="createElements()"><span>+</span></button>
        </form>

        <h4 class="hide" id="task-header">current tasks</h4>
            
        <form class="hide" id="container">
            <!--This is where the addTask elements go-->
        </form>
        
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.add-strikethrough{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-color: black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var row = 0;

function createElements(){ 

    //create Checkbox
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("id", "entryCheckbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("value", "unchecked");
    checkbox.setAttribute("onClick", "strikeTask(" + row +");")

    //create label using value from input box
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("id", "entryLabel"+row);
    label = document.getElementById("enter-task").value;

    //create deleteTask img
    var deleteTask = document.createElement("img");
    deleteTask.src = "images/x.svg";
    deleteTask.setAttribute("id", "delete-task");
    deleteTask.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(" + row +");")
    
    addTask(checkbox, label, deleteTask);
}

//This function appends the elements
function addTask(box, label, x){

    
    const tasks = document.getElementById("container");
    
    const newTask = document.createElement('div');
    newTask.classList.add('task-entries');

    const header = document.getElementById('task-header');

    //Makes sure input field is not empty
    if(label !== ""){

        //Show task container and header
        if(tasks.classList.contains("hide")){
            tasks.classList.replace('hide', 'task-container');
            header.classList.replace('hide', 'show-header')
        };
        //Append newTask to tasks container
        tasks.appendChild(newTask);
            newTask.setAttribute("id", "contentDiv"+row);
        newTask.appendChild(box);
        newTask.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
        newTask.appendChild(x);
            row++;
        
        //Resets input field after task is added
        document.getElementById("enter-task").value = null; 
    }
}



function deleteRow(ID){

    document.getElementById('contentDiv'+ID).remove();

    tasks = document.getElementById('container');
    header = document.getElementById('task-header');

    //Hide header and task container if no tasks exist
    if(tasks.children.length == 0){
        tasks.classList.replace('task-container', 'hide');
        header.classList.replace('show-header', 'hide');
    }
}

function strikeTask(ID){

    const x = document.getElementById('entryLabel'+ID);

    x.classList.toggle('add-strikethrough');
    
}
```

The strikeTask function is where my problem is; I can't figure out how to apply the class to the label when I click the corresponding checkbox

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You could look into `input:checked + label {...}` as a CSS way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check what is wrong is to inspect the element created. If you do that you will notice that you don't have a label within a div, only text within a div, because you create a text node with the value of the label, as seen here:

[image: example task element from inspect]

You cannot apply a class to a text node. So you have to create the label element, add text to the label element, then append it.

Here is updated Javascript that will do that:

```
var row = 0;

function createElements(){ 

    //create Checkbox
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("id", "entryCheckbox");
    checkbox.setAttribute("value", "unchecked");
    checkbox.setAttribute("onClick", "strikeTask(" + row +");")

    //create label using value from input box
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("id", "entryLabel"+row);
    label.textContent = document.getElementById("enter-task").value;

    //create deleteTask img
    var deleteTask = document.createElement("img");
    deleteTask.src = "images/x.svg";
    deleteTask.setAttribute("id", "delete-task");
    deleteTask.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(" + row +");")
    
    addTask(checkbox, label, deleteTask);
}

//This function appends the elements
function addTask(box, label, x){

    
    const tasks = document.getElementById("container");
    
    const newTask = document.createElement('div');
    newTask.classList.add('task-entries');

    const header = document.getElementById('task-header');

    //Makes sure input field is not empty
    if(label !== ""){

        //Show task container and header
        if(tasks.classList.contains("hide")){
            tasks.classList.replace('hide', 'task-container');
            header.classList.replace('hide', 'show-header')
        };
        //Append newTask to tasks container
        tasks.appendChild(newTask);
            newTask.setAttribute("id", "contentDiv"+row);
        newTask.appendChild(box);
        newTask.appendChild(label);
        newTask.appendChild(x);
            row++;
        
        //Resets input field after task is added
        document.getElementById("enter-task").value = null; 
    }
}



function deleteRow(ID){

    document.getElementById('contentDiv'+ID).remove();

    tasks = document.getElementById('container');
    header = document.getElementById('task-header');

    //Hide header and task container if no tasks exist
    if(tasks.children.length == 0){
        tasks.classList.replace('task-container', 'hide');
        header.classList.replace('show-header', 'hide');
    }
}

function strikeTask(ID){

    const x = document.getElementById('entryLabel'+ID);

    x.classList.toggle('add-strikethrough');
    
}
```

What I've changed: `label = document.getElementById("enter-task").value;` to `label.textContent = document.getElementById("enter-task").value;` inside `createElements()` & `newTask.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));` to `newTask.appendChild(label);` inside `addTask(...)`.

The label is created as you were creating it; its text content is set to the value of the enter-task input; the element is appended.

What you were doing was create a label element and giving it an id, but on the following line (`label = document.getElementById("enter-task").value;`) changing the value of the label variable to a text, then adding that text as a text node (`newTask.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));`).

Comment: Thank you! After using your suggestions, all I had to do was change:                                                
if(label !== "") to if(label.textContent !=="")       
and everything works perfectly now.